How to Identify Media Type such as if the media playing now is of type Music, AudioBook, Podcast etc
I am playing different media content from different sources. Following are the logs.

Podcast

browseItem = BrowseItem(mediaId=spotify:episode:67hGvhkaKGjuZ9ZlIkgxoU?contextUri=spotify%3Auser%3A31cfomjd6am737ganrnzd4rvj4xi%3Acollection%3Ayour-episodes&ref=your_library&pos=0,  title=THE COMPOUND EFFECT (DARREN HARDY), extras=Bundle[{android.media.IS_EXPLICIT=0, com.spotify.music.extra.IS_19_PLUS=0, com.spotify.music.extra.CAN_ADD_TO_COLLECTION=true,  android.media.extra.PLAYBACK_STATUS=0, androidx.media.MediaItem.Extras.COMPLETION_PERCENTAGE=0.0, android.media.metadata.DURATION=18142424, com.spotify.music.extra.TIME_LEFT_MS=18142424,  com.spotify.music.extra.COLLECTION_ICON_HINT=PLUS}], icon=content://com.spotify.music.mediaapi/image/ab6765630000ba8a48fd0be9cb1a3b185698eb04?cdn=i.scdn.co&transformation=ROUNDED_CORNER, subTitle=16 Jan • 5 hrs 3 mins, mediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=2, mDescription=THE COMPOUND EFFECT (DARREN HARDY), 16 Jan • 5 hrs 3 mins, null}, parentMediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=3, mDescription=Your Episodes, 6 episodes, null}) 
2. PocketCast
``browseItem = BrowseItem(mediaId=c23b6c60-df25-013c-8c81-0288c31939f3#f02f0ea9-de7e-4009-955e-a31218546ddb,
title=E2: Magic Mike, extras=Bundle[{android.media.extra.DOWNLOAD_STATUS=0, android.media.extra.PLAYBACK_STATUS=0}],
icon=content://au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts.media.library.provider/https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.pocketcasts.com%2Fdiscover%2Fimages%2Fwebp%2F480%2Fc23b6c60-df25-013c-8c81-0288c31939f3.webp, subTitle=S1 E2 • 6 May • 23m,
mediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=2, mDescription=E2: Magic Mike, S1 E2 • 6 May • 23m, }, parentMediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=1, mDescription=Broomgate: A Curling Scandal, null, null})
05-30 06:35:56.934 48921 48921 D JlrMedia_MediaBrowseStateUseCase$onBrowseItemCommand: browseItem = BrowseItem(mediaId=2797DCF8-1C93-4999-B52A-D1849736FA2C#3eb86d8a-04ec-4060-a61b-09146300ea30,
title=Part 7: Believe in Kids, extras=Bundle[{android.media.extra.DOWNLOAD_STATUS=0, android.media.extra.PLAYBACK_STATUS=0}],
icon=content://au.com.shiftyjelly.pocketcasts.media.library.provider/https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.pocketcasts.com%2Fdiscover%2Fimages%2Fwebp%2F480%2Fd8ee97e0-c9e2-013c-5cd3-0acc26574db2.webp, subTitle=S1 E7 • 16 May • 43m,
mediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=2,
mDescription=Part 7: Believe in Kids, S1 E7 • 16 May • 43m, }, parentMediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=1, mDescription=New Releases, null, null}) 
3. Amazon Music
browseItem = BrowseItem(mediaId=Easy Hits@Trending Playlists@DRAWER_HOME, title=Easy Hits,  extras=Bundle[{android.media.browse.CONTENT_STYLE_GROUP_TITLE_HINT=Trending Playlists, android.media.browse.CONTENT_STYLE_PLAYABLE_HINT=1}], icon=content://com.amazon.mp3.media.automotive.provider/%2Fdata%2Fuser%2F11%2Fcom.amazon.mp3.automotiveOS%2Fcache%2Fimg_cache%2F485920655.jpg, subTitle=Dua Lipa, Taylor Swift,  Beyoncé and more, mediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=2, mDescription=Easy Hits, Dua Lipa, Taylor Swift, Beyoncé and more, null}, parentMediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=1, mDescription=Home, null, null}) 05-30 06:39:09.836 48921 48921 D JlrMedia_MediaBrowseStateUseCase$onBrowseItemCommand: browseItem = BrowseItem(mediaId=Hot Right Now International@Trending Playlists@DRAWER_HOME,  title=Hot Right Now International, extras=Bundle[{android.media.browse.CONTENT_STYLE_GROUP_TITLE_HINT=Trending Playlists, android.media.browse.CONTENT_STYLE_PLAYABLE_HINT=1}],  icon=content://com.amazon.mp3.media.automotive.provider/%2Fdata%2Fuser%2F11%2Fcom.amazon.mp3.automotiveOS%2Fcache%2Fimg_cache%2F1789286262.jpg, subTitle=Hozier, Djo, Travis Scott and more, mediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=2, mDescription=Hot Right Now International, Hozier, Djo, Travis Scott and more, null}, parentMediaItem=MediaItem{mFlags=1, mDescription=Home, null, null})
There's no clear identifiers to understand if the playing media is a Music, Podcast, or an Audiobook.
Is there any way to identifying this?
I have looked into the mDescription information, it does give bit of info in terms of Episodes and duration of the content playing but that cannot be taken as the information to decide if the playing content is a Podcast or Music.
